# How reduce the number of retractions?

Tags: simplify3d, retraction

I want to print a phone case.

Compared to other models I have sliced, Simplify3D implements a lot of retraction moves.

Is this normal? How can I (*Should I?*) reduce the number of retractions?

What retraction settings would you recommend in Simplify3D?

[image: Screenshot of Simplify]

#### Settings

[image: Settings]

Comment: It's unclear what you ask of us, besides try to set the language of your slicer in English if possible, you have a bigger audience that can help you.

Comment: Hi Pedro and welcome to SE.3DP. English only on this site I'm afraid, but we *do* want to help you. Please edit your screen shots, as 0scar states, and your question can/will be reopened. Sorry about that. :-)

Comment: Don't worry about the retractions. The number you see seems perfectly fine.

Comment: @towe - as you appear to understand the question, do you want to submit an answer (and edit the question to be more understandable)? I could re-open it, so that you can do so, if you so wish

Comment: @towe What you pose is exactly the problem, but apparently not using an official version of the tool I can not do certain things.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales There are many free software tools you can use, the most popular are Ultimaker Cura and Slic3r. Your edit did not make the question more clear, are you interested in retraction settings for your printer? You don't define that with such a model, retraction settings are calibrated with specific retraction test models.

Comment: I have reinstated the images, and edited out the licensing in the image, I've put back in your new question.  I have tried to interpret your English and what you mean. However, it is still not 100% clear what you are trying to describe. Could you check the English grammar and describe more clearly your problem. Thanks :-) What does this mean:  `so many points compared with others models`? and this: `so much point cause the retraction?` - I think it is these two statements that are difficult to understand

Comment: @Greenonline I think the question should be clearer now, at least as far as I understand it.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales I don't think that's the case. Otherwise, it wouldn't need to be cracked.

Comment: the last screen shows Retrattion ditance, soßmething about aditional retraction, somethign with vertical retraction and then retraction speed. to answer those settings it would be good to know *what filament* is used... and the printer model (bowden vs. direct drive).

Comment: Enabling **combing** in the slicer would reduce the amount of retractions of that is what you are after?

Comment: @0scarmy 3d printer is Core XY DIY with bowden extruder, HotEnd V6, but i see that you suggestions is try to learn and use cura or slicer, i think the same, better settings and free tools. Thanks for your answer